# Is there a way that I can update my Flutter app without uploading to stores?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm developing an app for android in flutter. Only some people will use it so I do not want to upload it to PlayStore. The problem is, I can make it an apk and install it to devices but I can not update it. Is there a way or a program like TestFlight that I can also update the app for every devices using it?

Answer (score 1):

Without uploading it is not possible, but you have the option to upload it and don't make it publicly available.

The `Google Play Store` equivalent of Apple's `TestFlight` is creating an application in the `Google Play Console` and set up a release that is available for testing and not available for production (live presence in the Store).

This way you app will not be publicly available and you have to add the testers manually, just as it is with `TestFlight`. New versions will be delivered to the user's who installed the test application. One limitation is that the users need a `Google Account` to participate in the resting.

You can read about the details [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en).

Comment: So, I did not see anything about that on the page you mentioned but there is no any time limit for that right? I mean my app can still be on test for years?

Comment: I am not aware of any limits but I can't tell fore sure. I have draft applications in both Apple and Google stores for about a year now. In the Apple store a TestFlight build expires after 90 days or so, but if I upload a new build it will add another 90 days. I don't remember having something like that at Google.

Answer (score 1):

We use firebase to distribute test builds internally, check this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution

Comment: I will ask the same question but, is there any time limitation for it? Can my app still be on test for years?

Comment: As far as I know, there are no time limit for that